# Download de informações (Falha - Erro na rede)

Tags: r, download

Olá,

Estou com dificuldade para baixar dados do site da Anatel através do R

**Objetivo:** Baixar dados do site da Anatel

```
url = 'https://www.anatel.gov.br/dadosabertos/paineis_de_dados/acessos/'
for (filename in c('acessos_telefonia_fixa',
                    'acessos_banda_larga_fixa',
                    'acessos_tv_por_assinatura',
                    'acessos_telefonia_movel'
                    )){
 
   download.file(
     paste(url, filename, '.zip', sep=''),
     paste(folder, filename, '.zip', sep=''),
     method = 'libcurl',
     quiet = FALSE, mode = "wb", cacheOK = TRUE, timeout = 600000)
   gc()
 
   tmp <- tempfile()
   curl_download(paste(url, filename, '.zip', sep=''), tmp)
 
   print(file.info(paste(folder, filename, '.zip', sep='')))
   Sys.sleep(1)
   unzip(paste(folder, filename, '.zip', sep=''), list = TRUE, overwrite = TRUE, exdir = folder)
   gc(0)
   
 }
```

**Mensagem retorarnada**
Error in download.file(paste(url, filename, ".zip", sep = ""), paste(folder,  :
download from 'https://www.anatel.gov.br/dadosabertos/paineis_de_dados/acessos/acessos_banda_larga_fixa.zip' failed

**Situação**
Utilizo esse mesmo código para baixar vários outros arquivos, mas acredito que este não funciona devido até o download manual apresentar erro (de primeira).

Ao acessar o site da Anatel,  baixar manualmente os arquivos me retorna a mensagem "Falha - Erro na rede" e tenho que clicar para retomar o download, só assim o arquivo é totalmente baixado.

**Alguém poderia me ajudar?**

Fico à disposição caso não tenha sido clara minha explicação.
Agradeço desde já!!